# Any way to try catch whole Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got many Actions in my controller. Is there any way to try-catch whole Controller-document once instead inserting try-catch in every single action?

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - this is a bad practice. You should only catch exceptions you can handle.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thanks it was an useful information.

Answer (score 2):

you could override the OnException method

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    //your handling logic here
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Comment: Where do I put it in MVC?

Comment: @Rasme right in the controller which you want to handle errors

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can capture the `Application_Error` event, which will handle all exceptions that are not handled by a the action code. For more information see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I see, where should I put it in MVC?

Comment: It can go in [global.asax.cs](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/697469/About-Global-asax-File-in-MVC)

Comment: The downside is that this is global, not per-controller. Also, the original question still seems like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Agreed, `OnException` sounds like a better answer since it allows controller-specificity.  Can't speak to the XY problem.

Comment: @JohnWu Should `OnException` also be placed in global.asax?

Comment: No, it is an [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) of a base controller method that can be implemented in any class that inherits from ControllerBase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch any exception in all controllers in your MVC Application, then go for Global Exception Filters, this is a link that explains exactly how to catch and log global exceptions into database

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1260/exception-handling-logging-aspnet-mvc